# ThymeLeaf pass TimeStamp value

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to pass timestamp value in the format of "`2013-12-31 12:00:00.000007`", my java model class will take this property as "`java.sql.Timestamp`".

I tried passing using following html code, but it does not take the value entered in the field, instead it takes null value.

```
<td><input id="updateDateTime" name="updateDateTime" type="text" th:field="*{updateDateTime}"/></td>
```

As well in Controller class, i tried using custom binder as below, but still produces null values to "updateDateTime"

```
@InitBinder
    public void binder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Timestamp.class,
        new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            public void setAsText(String value) {
                try {
                    Date parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").parse(value);
                    setValue(new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime()));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    setValue(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you test if you maybe get a `ParseException` ?